# Angular httpClient can't get a String object

Tags: angular, typescript, rest, http, httpclient

I'm using Angular 6 to get a string from my Java REST Application and can't manage to parse/get the string

The REST API Service works just fine, it returns the String as expected, but in the Browser console I get this error

"SyntaxError: Unexpected token X in JSON at position 4 at JSON.parse"

I think this is linked to the Content-type of the Header

I've already tried to change the response type, but I can't send my data then.

```
login(userDTO:UserDTO):Observable<String> {
    let header:HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-type' : 'application/json',
    });
    return this.httpClient.post<String>('http://localhost:8080/login',  
userDTO, {headers: header});
  }
```

EDIT:
"Where are you getting the String object from? You should be using the string literal. – Edric 2 mins"

I'm getting it from a REST Java service which returns a String Java Object

Comment: Where are you getting the `String` object from? You should be using the `string` literal.

Comment: See the duplicate I've linked. In your case, remove the `<String>` and add the `responseType` property: `return this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:8080/login',  
userDTO, {headers: header, responseType: 'text'});`

Answer (score 1):

You need to expect `string` object not `String` object.
Just change

`return this.httpClient.post<String>('http://localhost:8080/login',

userDTO, {headers: header});`

to

`return this.httpClient.post<string>('http://localhost:8080/login',

userDTO, {headers: header});`

Expect return type also as `Observable<string>`